# issue with OFS in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a string containing this (field separator is the percentage sign), stored in a variable called data

```
201%jkhjfhn%kfhngjm%mkdfhgjdfg%mkdfhgjdfhg%mkdhfgjdhfg%kdfhgjgh%kdfgjhgfh%mkfgnhmkgfnh%k,gnhjkgfn%jkdfhngjdfng
```

I'm trying to print out that string replacing the percentage sign with a pipe but it seems harden than i thought:

```
echo ${data} | awk -F"%" 'BEGIN {OFS="|"} {print $0}'
```

I know I'm very close to it just not close enough.

I see that code as:

```
1 echo the variable value into a awk session
2 set field separator as "%"
3 set as output field separator "|"
4 print the line
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
echo "$data" | awk -F"%" 'BEGIN {OFS="|"} {$1=$1; print $0}'
```

From [awk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Field-Splitting-Summary)

> Finally, there are times when it is convenient to force awk to rebuild the entire
>   record, using the current value of the fields and OFS. To do this, use the seemingly
>   innocuous assignment:
>
> ```
> $1 = $1   # force record to be reconstituted
> print $0  # or whatever else with $0
> ```

---

Another lightweight way using only `tr` if you search an alternative for `awk` :

```
tr '%' '|' <<< "$data"
```

Comment: beaten by seconds, again :-) `$1=$1` trick forces awk to recalculate field-separator etc internaly

Answer (score 3):

Sputnick gave you the `awk` solution, but you don't actually need `awk` at all, just use your shell:

```
echo ${data//%/|}
```

Comment: Thx Mat, i actually have to use awk, what i have posted here its just a little art of a much longer awk script, but many thx for the tip