# AWK - parse second column from git status command

Tags: git, awk

I need to parse second column from output above - problem is, that if filename contains spaces and is surrounded by quotation marks.

Command:

```
$ git status -u -s
```

Output:

```
 D README.md
 D mail/falover.sh
?? "ahh/Nov nnsdfd file.txt"
?? fremover.sh
?? mail/ahooooj
?? mail/awww
?? mail/file_test
?? mail/git.sh
?? mail/test
```

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SO, so it means you need 2nd column as output?

Comment: Not especially helpful with awk, but `git status` has a `-z` option that separates items with ASCII NULs, which makes everything easily machine-readable in languages with binary byte-string manipulators.

Comment: @torek awk is record-based, not line-based like grep or sed, so it can parse NUL-separated input just as easily it can parse newline-separated or any other separated input. Just set `RS="\0"` and you're done.

Comment: @EdMorton: ah, ancient awk I'm used to didn't handle NUL well. So, OK, `-z` *is* helpful here :-)

Comment: You must've been using old, broken awk (the default awk on Solaris unfortunately). Never use that as its, well, old and broken. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `-porcelain=2` option that will remove the double quotes so that later you could use something like:

```
$ git status --porcelain=2 | cut -d" " -f9-
```

Note that this will only return tracked files if want to get all the files including the untracked ones also within quotes to try this;

```
$ git status --porcelain | cut -c4-
```

With `awk` this could be used:

```
$ git status --porcelain | awk '{$1 = ""; print substr($0, 2)}'
```

It works by setting the first column to `""` and then printing the full line `$0` but removing the space used as a delimiter using `substr`. (This will force `awk` to rebuild the entire record `$0` using spaces as the new delimiter - check @Ed Morton explanation in the comments & https://stackoverflow.com/a/15475578/1135424)

Check the [Porcelain Format Version 2](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_porcelain_format_version_2)

Comment: If you add `-u` like in the OPs question this will break on untracked files.

Comment: `$1 = ""` in your awk command will convert every sequence of any type of space into a single blank char and so will corrupt any file name that contains multiple contiguous blanks or any tabs.

Comment: @EdMorton in this case the idea is to replace completely the possible first 4 chars before before getting an space, so I don’t think it could corrupt the file names in the second column or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are missing something :-). When you assign a value to a field (e.g. `$1`), awk recompiles the whole record (`$0`) replacing all `FS`s with `OFS`s. So if you have input like `3<blank>"foo<tab>bar"` then doing `$1=""` will convert that to `<blank>"foo<blank>bar"` which changes the space in the file name between the quotes from a tab to a blank which corrupts it.

Comment: @EdMorton, does this applies only to gawk "Linux"? I  tested on BSD/macOS and didn't replace `<tab>` with space.

Comment: No, every awk does that, including the BSD one on macOS. It's an absolutely fundamental part of awk processing that many scripts rely upon. I've no idea what test you ran but it was the wrong test. Simply do `printf 'a\tb\n' | awk '{$1=$1}1'` to see it.

Comment: hi @EdMorton, many thanks for the example, doing a hex dump of the git output  I notice that the existing tab is represented with `\t` in hex `5c 74` not a tab  `09`  that's why it wasn't being replaced

Answer (score 1):

In case you only need those lines which have `"` and you need 2nd field means values from `"` to `"` then following may help you.

```
your_command | awk 'match($0,/".*"/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}'
```

In case you want to print file names when `"` is present in output with all other line(which don't have `"` in them) then following may help you.

```
your_command | awk 'match($0,/".*"/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);next} 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on if you want to retain the quotes or not:

```
$ sed -E 's/^ *[^ ]+ +//' file
README.md
mail/falover.sh
"ahh/Nov nnsdfd file.txt"
fremover.sh
mail/ahooooj
mail/awww
mail/file_test
mail/git.sh
mail/test

$ sed -E 's/^ *[^ ]+ +//; s/^"|"$//g' file
README.md
mail/falover.sh
ahh/Nov nnsdfd file.txt
fremover.sh
mail/ahooooj
mail/awww
mail/file_test
mail/git.sh
mail/test
```

If your sed doesn't support EREs by means of `-E` then:

```
$ sed 's/^ *[^ ]* *//; s/^"|"$//g' file
$ sed 's/^ *[^ ]* *//; s/^"//; s/"$//' file
```

Note that there is an edge case where this will fail and that is when your file name starts and ends with quotes (which is allowed for a UNIX file name). If that can happen then tell us about it in your question and include it in your sample input/output.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have `git status` calculate the status and then scrape the status off its output,  instead use `git ls-files -o` or `git ls-files -o --exclude-standard` to simply list the files you want directly.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't actually need to use `awk` a simple `cut` would be enough:

```
git status -u -s | cut -d" " -f2-
```

`-d" "` sets space as the delimiter and `-f2-` selects every field except the first

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this didn't work (in this case) because first column is aligned to right (first char is sometimes space).

Answer (score 0):

```
git status -u -s | awk -F '/' '{gsub("\"","");print $NF}'
```

if I understood the problem correctly